# Why I can't call methods directly from integer literal?

Tags: python

I can call methods directly from string literals:

```
>>> 'some_string'.__str__()
'some_string'
```

But when I try call it from integer literal, interpreter raise an error:

```
>>> 1.__str__()
File "<stdin>", line 1
1.__str__()
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why I can't call methods from integer, until I set it to some variable?

Comment: Try it like this: `int(1).__str__()`

Comment: @GáborFekete That's not calling it from the literal, like the string, where you do not need explicit `str()`.

Comment: Oh it seems you will have to use parenthesis around literals then.

Comment: @GáborFekete The linked duplicate has an answer that shows several ways to keep the parser from recognizing `1.` as a floating-point literal.

Comment: I saw it after my answer was posted, it's a really strange syntax error though.

Comment: The parser never sees the `.`; it's the same error you would get with something like `value = 1.; value __str__()`.